# Chronometer doesn't overwrite base value

Tags: android, chronometer

When I call chronometer.start(), the chronometer starts counting but the base value (00:00) is still there and it is not overwritten.

chronometer in my xml file looks like this

```
<Chronometer
 android:id="@+id/chronometer"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

and code in my Activity looks like this

```
 chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
 chronometer.start();
```

and the result looks like this

[image: chronometer]

Did anyone face the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing you need to do is to initialize chronometr first:

`chronometer = view.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
 chronometer.setText("");`

and then you can start your chronometr without overwriting

```
chronometer.start();
```